# The Squares alternating with triangular numbers and the largest odd divisor of $n^2+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, square-numbers

Consider the squares alternating with the triangular numbers $$a_n=0,0,1,1,4,3,9,6,16,10,25,15,36,21,49,28,64,36,81,\ldots$$

Is it trivial that $4a_n+1$ is the largest odd divisor of $n^2+1$. In particular it appears that $$4a_n+1 = 1,1,5,5,17,13,37,25,65,41,101,61,145,\ldots$$ In OEIS language:$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$4*$[A123596](http://oeis.org/A123596)$+1=$[A228564](http://oeis.org/A228564).

This is just based on pure speculation and checking out the first few terms. A counter example would be nice.

Comment: Wait, define $a_n$ for me?  I do not see how these numbers are made.

Comment: It is just the square numbers alternating with the triangular numbers?

Comment: Oh, so its a square number, then a triangle number, then a square number etc.  I get confused because alternating to me usually means $\pm$ in a series

Comment: Feel free to edit the title.

Comment: In your listing of $a_n$, you have forgotten one $1$. (I don't know whether $1^2$ or $\frac{1(1+1)}{2}$ is missing.)

Comment: Well, if $n$ is even, $n = 2m$, then $a_n = m^2$, so $4a_n + 1 = 4m^2 + 1 = (2m)^2 + 1 = n^2+1$. And if $n = 2m+1$ is odd, then $a_n = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$, so $4a_n + 1 = 2m(m+1) + 1 = \frac{1}{2}(4m^2 + 4m + 2) = \frac{(2m+1)^2 + 1}{2} = \frac{n^2+1}{2}$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: ^ pretty much that does it. But still how have you shown there is not a larger odd divisor ?

Comment: It is clear that $n^2 + 1$ cannot have a divisor greater than $n^2+1$. That settles the case for even $n$. For an even $k = 2r \in \mathbb{N}$, note that $k$ has no divisors between $r$ and $k$. For if $r < m < k$, then $k = 2r < 2m$, so $1 < \frac{k}{m} < 2$ and $m$ is not a divisor of $k$. So $r$ is the second largest of all divisors of $k$. And if $r$ is odd, it follows that $r$ is the largest odd divisor of $k$. This is the case for $k = n^2 + 1$ with odd $n$.